# javascriptの条件分岐について

Tags: javascript

初心者です。
javascriptの条件分岐についてつまづいたので質問させていただきます。

やりたいことは、要素を複数用意して、それぞれの要素をクリックしたらその要素のフラグがたち、次の処理ができるようになる、というものです。

具体的にいいますと、
要素1をクリック→「スクロールダウンしたらリンクaにリダイレクトされる」という処理が実行可能になる。
要素２をクリック→「スクロールアップしたらリンクbにリダイレクトされる」という処理が実行可能になる。
要素3をクリック→「スクロールが無効になる」という処理が実行可能になる。

そしてそれぞれの要素がクリックされている状態では別の要素の処理は無効状態になっている。
という感じです。

```
var a;

$("要素1").on('click', function () {
    a = 1;
});

$("要素2").on('click', function () {
    a = 2;
});

$("要素3").on('click', function () {
    a = 3;
});
```

という感じで要素をクリックしたら、それぞれの番号を変数aに振り、

```
switch(a){
  case 1:
    スクロールダウンしたらリンクaにリダイレクトされる処理
    break;
  case 2: 
    スクロールアップしたらリンクbにリダイレクトされる処理
    break;
  case 3: 
    スクロール無効の処理
    break;
}
```

という条件分岐で書いたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。
要素をクリックした時にaにそれぞれの番号は入るのは確認したのですが、条件分岐文が実行されません。
条件分岐自体が実行されてない？みたいです。（switch文の中に書いたalertやconsole.logも実行されませんでした。）
条件分岐をif文で書いたりしたのですが、うまくいかず、行き詰ってしまいました。

アドバイスお願いいたします。

Comment: ご自身が作成したhtmlおよびjavascriptも動く状態で質問に追加ください。スニペットで追記していただけるとよりよいです。

Comment: よければ実際に書いたコード全文をスニペットを使って書いてもらえればこのページ上でデモが表示できます。(といっても関係ないコードも含まれてそうですが……)

Comment: `switch`文は、実行される経路に入っているのですか？

Comment: jQueryを使っているのですか？

Answer (score 3):

```
function switchFunction(a) {
　switch(a){
  case 1:
    スクロールダウンしたらリンクaにリダイレクトされる処理
    break;
  case 2: 
    スクロールアップしたらリンクbにリダイレクトされる処理
    break;
  case 3: 
    スクロール無効の処理
    break;
　}
}

$("要素1").on('click', function () {
   switchFunction(1);
});

$("要素2").on('click', function () {
    switchFunction(2);
});

$("要素3").on('click', function () {
    switchFunction(3);
});
```

のように変更してみてください。